# Como somar medidas de um array?

Tags: javascript, angular

Pessoal gostaria de saber se seria possível somar os itens de um `arrays` com as posições correspondentes deles

```
var numeros = [30,18,8];
var numeros2 = [10,12,10];
```

por exemplo esse `[30,18,8] +  [10,12,10] = [40,30,18];`

Eu tenho um código que soma a quantidade total do array, mas não soma os dois juntos nas mesmas posições

```
var total = 0;
var numeros = [30,18,8];
var numeros2 = [10,12,10];

for ( var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++ ){
    total += numeros[i];
}

console.log(total);
```

Comment: o que acha? `const soma = numeros.map((num, index) => num + numeros2[index])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só criar uma terceira variável com um array vazio e preencher usando [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) no for que você já está fazendo, somando os elementos que estejam na mesma posição nos arrays.

```js
var total = 0;
var numeros = [30,18,8];
var numeros2 = [10,12,10];
var numeros3 = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++ ){
    total += numeros[i];
    numeros3.push((numeros[i] + numeros2[i]));
}

console.log(total);
console.log(numeros3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Duas soluções simples para obter o mesmo resultado

1 - o map ira retornar um novo array das somas dos  valores, considerando que os arrays tem a mesma quantidade de elementos.

```
var total = 0; 
var numeros = [30,18,8]; 
var numeros2 = [10,12,10];

function somar(valor, indice){
    
    total  =  (numeros2[indice] + valor);

    return total;
}

 var resultados = numeros.map(somar);
 
 console.log(resultados);
```

2 - se ambos arrays possuem o mesmo tamanho some pela posiçoes dos valores usando um loop que percorra pela posição , no teu código a variável total esta fora  do escopo do FOR ao acessa lá fora  o resultado sera a última soma do últimos 2 valores do array.

Uma declaração de um array novo para armazenar o resultado da soma de 2 arrays pode ser acessada fora do escopo do Loop.

```
var resultados = [];
for(var id in numeros){
    
    total = numeros[id] +numeros2[id];
    
    resultados.push(total);
 }

console.log(resultados);
```

Comment: Com a sua resposta o console.log retorna:
30 + 10 = 40
 18 + 12 = 30
 8 + 10 = 18
Gostaria que retornasse [40,30,18]

Comment: Gostaria que retornasse um array com o total das somas juntas

Comment: Editei a minha resposta, talvez tanto o   uso do FOR mais simples e do map pode ser um guia para entender e obter uma boa resolução da sua questão  